# The Moldy Square Grid

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, visual

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #14: Think inside the (very small) box!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7497/monthly-topic-challenge-14-think-inside-the-very-small-box).</sub>

---

What is in the middle space?

[image: grid puzzle]

Hint:

> The answer can be easily "read off" without computer assistance or special knowledge.
>  *However*, for the diehard puzzling enthusiasts, yes there is an optional secret message/hint hidden in the pixel ornamentation (THE extra dots and bars on the tAll nodes).

Hint 2:

> Although the question only asks about the middle one, each space holds a word. There is no cipher used, unless you are looking for a very helpful hint, in which case you should consult Samuel.

Hint 3:

> Seem hard? Reread everything. The way forward is hiding in plain sight. Also, web adventurer had the right idea to count things but I am not sure why they only counted some of the nodes.

Hint 4:

> The specifically worded question is very important to solving this. If you know the length, you can answer the question. And probably even if you don't.

Comment: A red question mark.

Comment: It seems we're supposed to do something with patterns that are on the same edges of the grid, maybe get difference of them?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, rot13( rnpu pryy'f yratgu naq jvqgu vf gjragl-fvk cvkryf, juvpu pnyyf gb zvaq gur nycunorg. ) But I don't know how to proceed from there. I've also been thinking about taking the difference of adjacent patterns, but I don't know what to do with the ones that vary greatly from their partners (e.g. the two pairs on the vertical edges of the middle cell)...

Comment: @oAlt I also noticed that. The 3x3 grid and the ridges often having period 3 make me think of phone keypad T9 codes, but I don't where to go from there.

Comment: rot13(Vf vg whfg pbvapvqrapr gung rnpu fdhner vf N-V va n cvtcra pvcure?)

Comment: Not sure if it's even useful, but [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIJU2.png) is a version of the image where each cell is exactly one pixel - Maybe for image manipulation purposes for the optional hint

Comment: @Mesentery When you find the answer, it will be undoubtedly correct and clearly the answer to the puzzle. If you are uncertain, then it's not it.

Comment: Don't suppose it's too early for a hint?

Comment: Has anyone started a chat (or similar) for solving this?

Comment: The hint has gotten pretty explicit. Trying not to give too much away since it looks like someone (not a poster here) has already guessed the answer, which is expected, and the final mechanism is not complex.

Comment: rot13(Jbhyq Fnzhry unir fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu zbefr pbqr? Gur ercrngvat funcrf pbhyq fbzrubj sbez fbzr fbeg bs zbefr?)

Comment: So it IS a counting exercise after all :O

Comment: @MWQOJYNWQA: [You bet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9nIX.png) (Not that it has helped me much ...)

Comment: @MOehm I actually think you're on the right track, as the top-left square (when read in a CCW direction) reads rot13(gurn, juvpu ersref gb gur pncvgny yrggref va gur svefg uvag).

Comment: @BlueHerring, [I know](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUweG.png)). The hint spells rot13(Gur nafjre vf guerr yrggref), but as I said, it hasn't helped me much and neither has the recently added tag. `:(`

Comment: @MOehm I think you may be missing the explanation for the tall and short nodes.

Comment: I feel like I would need to already know what it says before I am able to "read it off".

Comment: @codewarrior0 Exactly. There are now at least 3 users who "know the answer" but may not realize it. Anyone can solve this... with some thought.

Comment: Ah... this "anyone" person again. I'm sure *I* don't know what it says.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What is in the middle space?

> The Sun

How did I figure that out?

> Because of how many cipher puzzles I've done, the first thing I thought of upon seeing the puzzle was:
> - Each grid cell contains a word
> - Because the two or more mold patterns in each cell have the same number of humps, that number of humps must be the number of letters in the word
> - Because the tall humps are in the same positions in the corresponding mold of every pair of adjacent cells, those tall humps must correspond to letters which are shared between the two words.
>  So, the answer must be nine words which have those particular letters in common between adjacent pairs of words.

> It was not until several months later that I looked at the word "space" in the question and finally figured out what it says, starting by placing "SUN" above "SATURN". I hope this illustration shows what is going on:
>  [image]

> If I were a different kind of puzzler, I might have put the word lengths in order going clockwise and recognized them:  7, 5, 5, 4, 7, 6, 6, 7. I didn't even notice they were in order until I had placed all of the names! I'll feel a bit of shame on behalf of everyone that we didn't get this one sooner.

Comment: Well done! So ["something something"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124726/the-something-something) really meant "mouldy square". `;)`

Comment: "Oh no, not again! – Amoz" 

Comment: ^ Ah, now everything makes sense! Here, throw my shame into the mix for that final comment in your post...

Comment: Oh wow, so PrimNumbah and Amos coincidentally created the same type of puzzle!

Comment: I don't understand what the different shapes represent.

Comment: @msh210: Do you mean the different shapes at the tips? They form [a hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUweG.png), but are not important to the solution itself, which only distinguishes between small and large "nodes".

Comment: 'not again' was actually referring to https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122385/what-is-in-the-middle which also followed this one; I saw the gimmick for both puzzles immediately but dared not answer either (although I had an argument for "Straw"). Great work! I have an unofficial bounty for anyone solving one of my long outstanding puzzles, so that should be coming your way.

Comment: Aaaahh.  Thank you!  This was bothering me on and off.

Comment: Three people coming up with the same arrangement independently? That can't be concidence. I guess [Kepler's First Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion) should be rewritten. (And I begin to supect that the IAU demoted Pluto only to make everything fit nicely in a 3×3 square.)