# What is in the middle?

Tags: word, word-property

You have 4 options to guess what the question mark in the middle is.

[image]

Please try to solve without the hint first

Hint

> There are 3 commonalities for all the words

Comment: White space. Just white space.

Comment: @drd Out of curiosity, is the current accepted answer truly your originally intended solution? I always assumed the answer was rot13(N-fgenj) with reasoning/commonalities different from Stiv's, but couldn't say anything until now.

Comment: Yes it was the same reasoning I had

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been thinking for some time that the answer to this is:

> 4. THE BEST OF BOTH **WORLDS**

Because...

> These clues point to words that have specific letters in common with the names of the **planets** (i.e. worlds) in our solar system.

However, whenever I think I've pinpointed the specific rule, it seems that one of my words produces an exception, so I'm not 100% sure I have identified all of them exactly correctly. Here are my contenders though:

> A [SURICATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meerkat) = **MEERKAT**
>
>  A BAD NEWS FOR COMPUTERS = **VIRUS**
>
>  WHERE WE ARE = **EARTH**
>
>  WHAT SOLDIERS SOMETIMES DO = **MARCHES**
>
>  ONE OF THE DOZEN DECIDERS = **JURYSPEAKER**
>
>  A METAL FASTNER AND PIERCER = **SAFETYPIN**
>
>  THE ARMPITS = **UNDERARMS**
>
>  A DIRECTION = **NORTHERN HEMISPHERE**?
>
>  With these word choices we can see that:
>
>  1. Every word begins with the same letter as the respectively ordered planet:
>
>  **M**eerkat/**M**ercury, **V**irus/**V**enus, **E**arth/**E**arth, **M**arches/**M**ars, **J**uryspeaker/**J**upiter, **S**afetypin/**S**aturn, **U**nderarms/**U**ranus, **N**orthernHemisphere/**N**eptune.
>
>  2. Not only that, but every word (except Virus) also contains the second and third letters of the respectively ordered planet:
>
>  **ME**e**R**kat/**MER**cury, [Virus/Venus], **EAR**th/**EAR**th, **MAR**ches/**MAR**s, **JU**rys**P**eaker/**JUP**iter, **SA**fe**T**ypin/**SAT**urn, **U**nde**RA**rms/**URA**nus, **N**orth**E**rnHemis**P**here/**NEP**tune.
>
>  3. Additionally, every word (except Meerkat) ends with the same letter as the respectively ordered planet:
>
>  [Meerkat/Mercury], Viru**S**/Venu**S**, Eart**H**/Eart**H**, Marche**S**/Mar**S**, Juryspeake**R**/Jupite**R**, Safetypi**N**/Satur**N**, Underarm**S**/Uranu**S**, Neptun**E**/NorthernHemispher**E**.

Criticisms of my approach:

> A) Clearly, 'MEERKAT' and 'VIRUS' are exceptions to these rules - I may not yet have these correct. (Could 'Meerkatty' be correct instead? No clue yet as to a suitable 'Virus' alternative though...)
>
>  B) 'Northern Hemisphere' is not really 'a direction', but given that I was able to find words containing the first three letters of each of the other planets, this is the closest I have for words of the form n*e*p*e
>
>  C) I have 'Earth' for both the planet and its substitute word, rendering it trivially true for all the rules - this may not be the OP's intention...
>
>  These things considered, I am positive that MARCHES, JURYSPEAKER, SAFETYPIN and UNDERARMS fit these rules too well for them not to be intentional. (I considered JURYPERSON initially, until I stumbled upon one that actually ended in 'R' rather than merely containing it...)

Despite these, I think this must be pretty darn close to the OP's intention, hence my posting this answer after almost 2 months of remaining unanswered.

One final note on the choice to go 'in the middle':

> I chose the one cluing 'WORLDS' because this is what the other boxes surrounding it clue, but an argument could also be made for '2 THE SUNSHINE STATE' - not because of Florida, but because these planets *go around* the **SUN**...

Comment: Rot13(V jbhyq fhttrfg: znepu, whebe, abegurnfgrea, jvgu gur ehyr gung ng yrnfg guerr bs gur yrggref zngpu sebz gur cersvk be fhssvk bs gur cynarg. ZREphel, IraHF, ZNEf, RNEGU, WHcvgrE, FNGheA, HENahF, ARcghaR.)