# The Something Something

Tags: knowledge, visual, pattern

**What numbers should replace the question marks? Why?**

---

[image]

---

Comment: Oh no, not again!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think the answer is

> [image: Ans]

because

> The outermost squares in the grid represent the planets going around the **Sun** (the white square in the centre). The top left square represents **Mercury** and going clockwise around the outermost squares, each square represents the planets in increasing order of distance from the Sun. The colour of the square is used to indicate the colour of the planet. **Saturn**, of course, which is famous for its rings has a thin blue line across its square. (That was also my breakthrough for this puzzle). 
>  The numbers represent the number of moons that each planet has. So, the missing numbers belong to **Jupiter** and **Saturn**, which have **95** and **146** moons respectively.
>  As mentioned in the comments by Stiv, the "Something Something" in the title refers to the **Solar System**.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0A7G.gif

Comment: In which case, 'Something Something' in the title would probably represent rot13(Fbyne Flfgrz)...

Comment: @Stiv Oh nice catch, didn't notice that.

Comment: Correct, well done! And yes, title refered to what @Stiv wrote